# Hibernate (JPA) - Weird update for no reason

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, sql-update

I have an application which accesses an oracle-db which is storing contacts in a table. create, read and update is working fine. But delete won't work only sometimes for some weird reason.

When i start my application, i load all current contacts from my db and put them in a javafx-table. i let hibernate show me all it's sql and thats all it did until here. It only did once a select. Now if i directly start to delete contacts it works fine for 3-4 contacts and then i get an error which tells me, that hibernate tried to run an update-statement where it used as id null. why is hibernate doing this?

this is total nonsense. i double and tripple checked it and there is no db-action running between the select statement and the deletes. why does hibernate do an update in the middle of nowhere without any reason when i tell it to delete?

Here you see all coude and information you can possibly need to understand my situation

```
public void refresh() {
List<OrganisationContact> allContacts = EntityStore.ORGA_CON_REPO
    .readAllWithDetails();
contactTable.getItems().setAll(allContacts);
}
```

This is the method in my repository

```
    @Override
public List<OrganisationContact> readAllWithDetails() {
    try {
        JPAJinqStream<Contact> stream = getStreamForTable(Contact.class);
        List<OrganisationContact> organisationContactList = new ArrayList<OrganisationContact>();
        try {
            stream.forEach(con -> organisationContactList
                    .add(new OrganisationContact(con)));
        } catch (javax.persistence.PersistenceException exception) {
            NoReplyFromDatabaseException.showErrorDialog();
            throw new NoReplyFromDatabaseException(exception);
        }
        stream.close();
        return organisationContactList;
    } catch (javax.persistence.PersistenceException exception) {
        NoReplyFromDatabaseException.showErrorDialog();
        throw new NoReplyFromDatabaseException(exception);
    }
}
```

This is the method in my abstract repository my normal repository is using

```
    protected <TableEntity>JPAJinqStream<TableEntity> getStreamForTable(final Class<TableEntity> pEntityClass) {
    if (this.manager != null && this.factory != null && this.provider != null) {
        if (this.manager.isOpen() && this.factory.isOpen()) {
            return this.provider.streamAll(this.manager, pEntityClass);
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

manager is an instance of EntityMananger
factory is an instance of EntityManagerFactory
provider is an instance of JinqJPAStreamProvider

This is the code which is executed when you delete a contact

```
    @FXML
public void onDelete() {

EntityStore.ORGA_CON_REPO.delete(EntityStore.CURRENT_CONTACT);
if (!UnitOfWork.closeTransaction(EntityStore.ORGA_CON_REPO, true)) {
    // error occured
}

// ignore that stuff
EntityStore.CURRENT_CONTACT = null;
ModeManager.clearMode();
ModeManager.refreshTable();
}
```

ORGA_CON_REPO is my repository from above
UnitOfWork knows all existing repositories (in this case only 1 exists) and handles it's transactions

This is my UnitOfWork class

```
public final class UnitOfWork {

private static final Map<AbstractRepository<?>, EntityManager> units = new HashMap<AbstractRepository<?>, EntityManager>();

private UnitOfWork() {
}

/* PUBLIC */
/**
 * Executes a commit/rollback and closes the transaction for the passed
 * repository.
 * 
 * @param pRepository
 *            The repository the transaction belongs to.
 * @param pCommit
 *            If this parameter is <code>true</code>, the transaction will
 *            be commited before closing. If it is <code>false</code>, the
 *            transaction will be rolled back before closing.
 *            @return true if the transaction has been closed successfully, false if an error occured while closing or the manager was null
 */
public synchronized static boolean closeTransaction(
    final AbstractRepository<?> pRepository, final boolean pCommit) {
EntityManager manager = units.get(pRepository);
if (manager != null) {
    try {
    EntityTransaction t = manager.getTransaction();
    if (t.isActive()) {
        if (pCommit) {
        t.commit();
        } else {
        t.rollback();
        }
    }
    units.remove(pRepository);

    return true;
    } catch (PersistenceException pException) {
    pRepository.resetManager(false);
    units.remove(pRepository);
    // TODO: log and throw
    }
}
return false;
}

/* PROTECTED */
/**
 * Starts a new transaction in a new unit of work.
 * 
 * @param pRepository
 *            The repository the transaction belongs to.
 * @param pManager
 *            The EntityManager of the passed repository.
 * @return <code>true</code> if the transaction has been started
 *         successfully, <code>false</code> if the manager is closed or one
 *         of the parameters is null.
 */
protected synchronized static boolean beginTransaction(
    final AbstractRepository<?> pRepository,
    final EntityManager pManager) {
if (pRepository != null || pManager != null) {
    if (pManager.isOpen()) {
    if (!units.containsKey(pRepository)) {
        EntityTransaction t = pManager.getTransaction();
        if (!t.isActive()) {
        t.begin();
        }
        units.put(pRepository, pManager);
    }
    return true;
    }
}
return false;
}
```

}

This is the delete method of my repository

```
    @Override
public boolean delete(OrganisationContact pEntity) {
    Contact contactEntity = pEntity.getContact();
    return remove(contactEntity);
}
```

which is using the method of my abstract repository

```
protected boolean remove(final Object pEntity) {
    if (this.canManagerExecute(pEntity)) {
        if (this.beginTransaction()) {
            this.manager.remove(pEntity);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

 private boolean canManagerExecute(final Object pEntity) {
    if (this.manager != null && pEntity != null) {
        return this.manager.isOpen();
    }
    return false;
}
```

which is using hibernate.
And this are my entities

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "reskonverw")
public class Contact {
@Column(name = "phonenumber")
private String phoneNumber;
@Column(name = "firstname")
private String firstName;
@Column(name = "surname")
private String surname;
@Column(name = "email")
private String email;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@Column(name="id")
private int id;
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Organisation organisation;
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Role role;

public Contact() {

}

public Contact(String phoneNumber, String firstName, String surname,
    String email, Organisation organisation, Role role) {
this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
this.firstName = firstName;
this.surname = surname;
this.email = email;
this.organisation = organisation;
this.role = role;
}

public String getPhoneNumber() {
return phoneNumber;
}

public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
}

public String getFirstName() {
return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getSurname() {
return surname;
}

public void setSurname(String surname) {
this.surname = surname;
}

public String getEmail() {
return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
this.email = email;
}

public Organisation getOrganisation() {
return organisation;
}

public void setRole(final Role pRole) {
role = pRole;
}

public Role getRole() {
return role;
}

public void setOrganisation(Organisation organisation) {
this.organisation = organisation;
}

public int getId() {
return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
this.id = id;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
return new StringBuilder(surname).append(", ").append(firstName)
    .toString();
}
}

@Entity
@Table(schema = "reskonverw")
public class Country {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
private int id;
private String name;

public Country() {
}

public Country(String cName) {
    this.name = cName;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return name;
}
}

@Entity
@Table(schema = "reskonverw")
public class Organisation {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
private int id;
private String name;
private String zipcode;
private String housenumber;
private String city;
private String street;
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Country country;

public Organisation() {
}

public Organisation(String name, String zipcode, String housenumber,
        String city, String street, Country country) {
    this.name = name;
    this.zipcode = zipcode;
    this.housenumber = housenumber;
    this.city = city;
    this.street = street;
    this.country = country;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getZipcode() {
    return zipcode;
}

public void setZipcode(String zipcode) {
    this.zipcode = zipcode;
}

public String getHousenumber() {
    return housenumber;
}

public void setHousenumber(String housenumber) {
    this.housenumber = housenumber;
}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

public String getStreet() {
    return street;
}

public void setStreet(String street) {
    this.street = street;
}

public Country getCountry() {
    return country;
}

public void setCountry(Country country) {
    this.country = country;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return name;
}
}

@Entity
@Table(schema = "reskonverw")
public class Role {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
private int id;
private String description;

public Role() {
}

public Role(String rDescription) {
    this.description = rDescription;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return description;
}
}
```

My session bean which is used to be displayed in the javafx table

```
public class OrganisationContact {
private Contact contact;

public OrganisationContact(Contact contact) {
    this.contact = contact;
}

/* Entities */
public Organisation getOrganisation() {
    return contact.getOrganisation();
}

public void setOrganisation(Organisation organisation) {
    contact.setOrganisation(organisation);
}

public Contact getContact() {
    return contact;
}

public void setContact(Contact contact) {
    this.contact = contact;
}

public Role getRole() {
    return contact.getRole();
}

public void setRole(final Role pRole) {
    contact.setRole(pRole);
}

public Country getCountry() {
    return contact.getOrganisation().getCountry();
}

public void setCountry(final Country pCountry) {
    contact.getOrganisation().setCountry(pCountry);
}

/* EntityStats */
// Organisation

public String getOrganisationName() {
    return contact.getOrganisation().getName();
}

public void setOrganisationName(final String pName) {
    contact.getOrganisation().setName(pName);
}

public String getOrganisationZipcode() {
    return contact.getOrganisation().getZipcode();
}

public void setOrganisationZipcode(final String pZipcode) {
    contact.getOrganisation().setZipcode(pZipcode);
}

public String getOrganisationHousenumber() {
    return contact.getOrganisation().getHousenumber();
}

public void setOrganisationHouseNumber(final String pHouseNumber) {
    contact.getOrganisation().setHousenumber(pHouseNumber);
}

public String getOrganisationCity() {
    return contact.getOrganisation().getCity();
}

public void setOrganisationCity(final String pCity) {
    contact.getOrganisation().setCity(pCity);
}

public String getOrganisationStreet() {
    return contact.getOrganisation().getStreet();
}

public void setOrganisationStreet(final String pStreet) {
    contact.getOrganisation().setStreet(pStreet);
}

// Contact
public String getFirstName() {
    return contact.getFirstName();
}

public void setFirstName(final String pFirstName) {
    contact.setFirstName(pFirstName);
}

public String getSurname() {
    return contact.getSurname();
}

public void setSurname(final String pSurname) {
    contact.setSurname(pSurname);
}

public String getEmail() {
    return contact.getEmail();
}

public void setEmail(final String pEmail) {
    contact.setEmail(pEmail);
}

public String getPhoneNumber() {
    return contact.getPhoneNumber();
}

public void setPhoneNumber(final String pPhoneNumber) {
    contact.setPhoneNumber(pPhoneNumber);
}

// Country
public String getOrganisationCountryName() {
    return contact.getOrganisation().getCountry().getName();
}

// Role
public String getRoleDescription() {
    return contact.getRole().getDescription();
}

public void setRoleDescription(final String pDescription) {
    contact.getRole().setDescription(pDescription);
}
}
```

EDIT: Here the sql hibernate prints on my console first when it does the select at the programmstart:

```
Hibernate: 
select
    * 
from
    ( select
        contact0_.id as id1_0_,
        contact0_.email as email2_0_,
        contact0_.firstname as firstname3_0_,
        contact0_.organisation_id as organisation_id6_0_,
        contact0_.phonenumber as phonenumber4_0_,
        contact0_.role_id as role_id7_0_,
        contact0_.surname as surname5_0_ 
    from
        reskonverw.Contact contact0_ ) 
where
    rownum <= ?
Hibernate: 
select
    organisati0_.id as id1_2_0_,
    organisati0_.city as city2_2_0_,
    organisati0_.country_id as country_id7_2_0_,
    organisati0_.housenumber as housenumber3_2_0_,
    organisati0_.name as name4_2_0_,
    organisati0_.street as street5_2_0_,
    organisati0_.zipcode as zipcode6_2_0_,
    country1_.id as id1_1_1_,
    country1_.name as name2_1_1_ 
from
    reskonverw.Organisation organisati0_ 
left outer join
    reskonverw.Country country1_ 
        on organisati0_.country_id=country1_.id 
where
    organisati0_.id=?
Hibernate: 
select
    role0_.id as id1_3_0_,
    role0_.description as description2_3_0_ 
from
    reskonverw.Role role0_ 
where
    role0_.id=?
```

Here the sql hibernate prints on my console when it does the delete at the buttonclick (select because i update all entities afterwards because there are multiple clients):

```
Hibernate: 
delete 
from
    reskonverw.Contact 
where
    id=?
Hibernate: 
select
    * 
from
    ( select
        contact0_.id as id1_0_,
        contact0_.email as email2_0_,
        contact0_.firstname as firstname3_0_,
        contact0_.organisation_id as organisation_id6_0_,
        contact0_.phonenumber as phonenumber4_0_,
        contact0_.role_id as role_id7_0_,
        contact0_.surname as surname5_0_ 
    from
        reskonverw.Contact contact0_ ) 
where
    rownum <= ?
```

Here the sql hibernate prints on my console when it does an update instead of a delete at the buttonclick (no select because it crashes before):

```
Hibernate: 
update
    reskonverw.Contact 
set
    email=?,
    firstname=?,
    organisation_id=?,
    phonenumber=?,
    role_id=?,
    surname=? 
where
    id=?
Jul 08, 2015 8:05:12 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 1407, SQLState: 72000
Jul 08, 2015 8:05:12 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: ORA-01407: Aktualisieren von ("RESKONVERW"."CONTACT"."ORGANISATION_ID") zu NULL nicht möglich
```

For not german ppl, 'ERROR: ORA-01407: Aktualisieren von ("RESKONVERW"."CONTACT"."ORGANISATION_ID") zu NULL nicht möglich' means 'error - setting resconverw.contact.organisation_id to null not possible

Comment: So, almost unknown code made with unknown entities causes an unknown SQL update query to be executed. How could we help?

Comment: Well there you go, i just didn't post it because it is a lot and the lines i showed to you was practicly almost everything i did. Entities are normal entitybeans and my repositories are all accessing hibernatefunctions in the background except for the select. the select at the beginning is using jinq which is also using hibernates/jpas entitymanagerfactory

Comment: I also should say, that the implementation of the abstract repository is done by younger ppl in our factory who are learning java atm

Comment: Maybe you could also post the statements that hibernate executes, to see what entity was updates with a null ID. Also the code looks very crappy...

Comment: Maybe you could simplify your problem to the offending statements, and refine the issue accurately.  You start your problem by saying all you are doing is a simple select and then delete, but the very first code block shows you are making changes - not just a simple select.  contactTable.getItems().setAll(allContacts) could be making changes.  If you drill down further, you are populating the list with new OrganisationContact(con) calls.  This is not a simple question type issue; you need to step through your code and understand what it is doing, and break that out if it isn't clear

Comment: I did. contactTable is my javafx table. it's pure gui and this method fills it with objects of organisationcontact. organisationcontant isn't even a entity in my database. and i already steped through it, it isnt doing anything which could make hibernate to do an update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contact has a foreginkey to Organisation. It is linked by the id of the Organisation. When i delete the Contact, Hibernate sometimes tries to set the foreginkey to null before deleting it. Not always for some reason i couldn't figure out yet. In my db i had setup a constraint which prevent the foregin key from becomeing null. And that is why the update failed and i got an exception. I removed the constraint and since then it is working.

Thanks all for the help